# 64-bit solution ASP.NET with C# and one project 32-bit in C++

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm trying to put on IIS (Windows Server 2012 x64) project, that have one ASP.NET web application x64 with one project in C++ that is both 32- and 64-bit. I've tried to replace the C++ project DLL's both 32- and 64-bit. Also I've tried many configurations: turn on and off "Prefer 32-bit" in Visual Studio, change AnyCPU (for all projects) to 64-bit, turn on and off "Enable 32-bit applications" in IIS. The problem is that IIS don't see the C++ project DLL (which should see, it's in the same folder) or can't load because of incorrect format. I would like to run the whole solution in 64-bit with eventually 32-bit C++ project, so changing everything to 32-bit would not be the right solution. Is there a way to put everything on IIS to run the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to align the platforms to the same [*bitness*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bitness). That is, you either:

1. Compile both the web application and the C++ referenced project to 32-bit and set *Enable 32-Bit Application* to `True` for the IIS application pool.
2. Compile both the web application and the C++ referenced project to 64-bit and set *Enable 32-Bit Application* to `False` for the IIS application pool.

If the C++ project has some other dependency on a 32-bit DLL which doesn't have a 64-bit version, that will be a problem. In this case, you have no option but to align everything to 32-bit.

Comment: Yes, that was one thing, and the other one was put the "Release" versions of applications. Debug versions were looking for debug versions of Visual C++ Redistributables DLL's.

Comment: Also proper (32-/64-bit) version of Redistributables is needed.

Comment: Once again: needed to remove compiler or linker directive WIN32 in C++ project.

Comment: And the last thing: Visual Studio IIS Express runs only 32-bit applications locally.